# How do I clear Image from JPanel?

Tags: jpanel

I use `JFileChooser` to browse an Image to my `JPanel`. When I want to browse second Image, the first Image is still there!

Actually, I want to know, how can I clear first Image from `JPanel` when I browse second Image?

Notice: I already used `JPanel.repaint()` and also `JPanel.revalidate()`, but they did not work.